# How do I unlock the Mission Accomplished Achievement?

Tags: achievements, spiral-knights

I'm trying to get the super neato hat for TF2 that can be unlocked simply by going through the first level of the Clockwork in Spiral Knights.

The method of unlocking it is as follows:

> Reach the first Clockworks Terminal

I thought that I had done this...twice.  I went up to a terminal in Haven, entered Clockworks Level 1, proceeded to bash a bunch of wolves and make my way through the level, finishing at the elevator.

I even went down another level (which ended up being a Garden).

I thought that getting through the first level and reaching the terminal/elevator at the end would be sufficient.....what am I missing?

Comment: Is the hat still up for grabs?

Comment: In my inbox I have a letter from Saxton Hale saying it is so...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit confusing, but several levels into the clockworks (regardless of which gate you pick), there's a "Clockworks terminal" level. That level is basically a midpoint of the tier, where you can heal up for free, and purchase recipes from a vendor. That's what you need to reach for the achievement (and hat). Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, ok then.  I'll go look for that.  I thought by 'Terminal' they just meant the endpoint of a level.

Comment: To further clarify, the Terminal is level 4, reached after making it through half of Tier 1. The other tiers have clockwork terminals as well, at depths of 13 and 23.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you completed all mission's before you reach the first clockworks terminal

If it still doesnt work try uninstalling and installing the Spiral Knights game

Still doesnt work? Try uninstalling and installing TF2